# Bootstrap Workflow with Git Submodules- Is it Correct?

Tags: git, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, workflow

I have been working with Bootstrap for awhile now, but I have recently started tinkering with integrating bootstrap into my repos. I am attempting to create a workflow where the following exist without despair:

- I have a GitHub repo with my site's "dist" files (front-end/html/css/production) that I can update frequently.
- I have a directory that I can keep Bootstrap, jQuery, Holder and Initializr up-to-date in.
- I can put those updates into my "Dist" directory whenever I feel so fit.
- I can add my own "custom" css on top of Bootstrap-generated CSS.

**So I have come up with the following so far:**

- GitHub repo ("mySite")

  - **/dist** (where my "live" files reside)
  - **/src** (where the various utitlities like Bootstrap reside and are updated)
  - Each dependency in the **/src** directory is a Git Submodule. I can update them whenever I feel like, build locally and (somehow) update the files in the /dist directory with those updates.

I have hit a sort of road block though... Whenever I build Bootstrap locally using "***npm install***" and "***grunt***", new files and directories are created in "**/src/bootstrap**". So the next time I attempt to do a commit/push, there are new files that end up in this weird limbo where I can do "***git add -A***" "***git commit -m "Built Bootstrap" -a***" "***git push origin master***", but (obviously) nothing is changed in my "**mySite**" repo. This is because the **/src/bootstrap** directory is a submodule.

I have no idea where the pushed files ended up, which bugs me. But going back to my issue, Is there a better/"correct" way to achieve what I wish to? Is what I'm doing a legit bootstrap workflow?

Also, do I need to create a "**/src/custom.less**" file that imports "**bootstrap.less**" and add my own custom CSS to it? Is that an acceptable way to add custom CSS to a Bootstrap site?

I have always just downloaded Bootstrap and included the css and js, then added an addtional include of "styles.css" that contains my own CSS. This is great and all, but it can make for a bulky site and I would prefer not to stack styles anymore.

Comment: /src/bootstrap seems better to me because you can upgrade easily..  in a self contained folder.. I think that is the behavior most use

Answer (score 0):

I settled on using the following structure:

- /dist (For all "Live" files)
- /libs (For all dependencies (Like Bootstrap))
- /src (For my own LESS files)

I can clone, modify, etc. with no issue. I still don't see the difference between this style of workflow, and using a git submodule. It seems like submodules would be the way to go... But this worked good for me. I 'll post back for other newcomers to Bootstrap that are trying to establish a decent workflow!